# Can a button for Lock Anchor be created in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

Is it possible to add a button to the Quick Access Toolbar in Word that "Lock Anchor" on images?

Usually I would, right click to image, go to Size and Position > Position > Lock Anchor..but this is long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Quick Access Toolbar Solution**

You can add the Object Position button to the Quick Access Toolbar.

1. Go to File - Options - Quick Access Toolbar.
2. Select **Picture Tools | Format tab** under *Choose commands from*.
3. Scroll down to Object Position and select it.

Once you click the arrow next to **Object Position** from the Quick Access Toolbar, you'll still have to select **More Layout Options...** and check the *Lock Anchor* box.  Unfortunately, Lock Anchor doesn't appear to be directly in the list of commands you can add to the Quick Access Toolbar.

**Macro Solution**

You can use the following macro to lock anchors for *all* shapes in the document.

> `Sub LockAnchor()
> ' LockAnchor Macro`

Dim ShapesLoop As Integer
Dim i As Integer

ShapesLoop = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count
For i = 1 To ShapesLoop
ActiveDocument.Shapes(i).LockAnchor = True
Next i

End Sub

You can then add it to the Quick Access Toolbar using the same process as above, except that you'd select the macro from Macros in step 2.